# Cpan Issues with WWW::Facebook::API

Tags: perl, ubuntu-14.04, cpanm

I have tried quite hard to figure out what is wrong, I have tried installing with `sudo` and just using the `cpanm` commands. But to no avail. I have tralled this forum looking for the answer. Here is the result when I run `cpanm` command with `sudo` powers:

```
--> Working on WWW::Facebook::API
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/U/UN/UNOBE/WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Crypt::SSLeay
--> Working on Crypt::SSLeay
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Crypt-SSLeay-0.72 ... N/A
! Configure failed for Crypt-SSLeay-0.72. See ./work/1410459602.1732/build.log for details.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Crypt::SSLeay' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18.
```

same thing when I run just `cpanm`... i have `open-ssl` installed.But i seem to be going in a circle of nowhere... Any suggestions would be much appreciated

```
    Warning: prerequisite Crypt::SSLeay 0 not found.
    Checking if your kit is complete...
    Looks good
    Writing Makefile for WWW::Facebook::API
    Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
    -> OK
    Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
    Checking if you have Readonly 0 ... Yes (2.00)
    Checking if you have LWP::UserAgent 0 ... Yes (6.06)
    Checking if you have JSON::Any 0 ... Yes (1.36)
    Checking if you have version 0 ... Yes (0.9902)
    Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
    Checking if you have Crypt::SSLeay 0 ... No
    Checking if you have Digest::MD5 0 ... Yes (2.52)
    Checking if you have Time::HiRes 0 ... Yes (1.9725)
    ==> Found dependencies: Crypt::SSLeay
    Searching Crypt::SSLeay on cpanmetadb ...
    --> Working on Crypt::SSLeay
    Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
    -> OK
    Unpacking Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
    Entering Crypt-SSLeay-0.72
    Checking configure dependencies from META.json
    Checking if you have ExtUtils::CBuilder 0.280205 ... Yes (0.280210)
    Checking if you have Try::Tiny 0.19 ... Yes (0.19)
    Checking if you have Getopt::Long 0 ... Yes (2.39)
    Checking if you have Path::Class 0.26 ... Yes (0.33)
    Configuring Crypt-SSLeay-0.72
    Running Makefile.PL
```

(there was an informational excerpt here, not error info.)

```
openssl-version.c:2:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
Failed to build and link a simple executable using OpenSSL
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Crypt-SSLeay-0.72. See ./.cpanm/work/1410459602.1732/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Crypt::SSLeay' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18.
```

now im confused, because i have `open-ssl` installed.

Comment: You need to examine this log file: `See ./work/1410459602.1732/build.log for details.` for why Crypt-SSLeay-0.72 failed to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that it complains about a missing header files and you say you're running Ubuntu, it's very likely that the problem is that you don't have the development package for OpenSSL installed. Try installing libssl-dev and see if that helps.